# Shortcuts.app Copy Image Text

Tags: command-line, shortcuts-app

The `Shortcuts` app can be run from the `CLI`:

```
shortcuts run 'Extract Image Text' -i /Users/rich/Desktop/alpha.png -o /Users/rich/Desktop/imagetext.txt
```

However, the structure of the actual `Shortcut` is confusing.  I want to run the script and copy the sniffed text into the `clipboard` for further processing.  I don't know what instructions I need to get this done.

Right now I have **Extract text from File** and **Copy Text from Image to clipboard** however this doesn't seem to work, given the structure above:

```
shortcuts run 'Extract Image Text' -i /Users/rich/Desktop/alpha.png
```

Does anybody know how I have to structure this for it to grab the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. The initial box was supplied by the app itself. I've ticked "Use as Quick Action", but it works on the CLI as well.

[image]

Comment: OK, interesting.  I had to start again, as the actions change scope depending on what is currently in the workflow.  So I had to delete some actions and re-choose them in order for them to work.